# barplot does not work with a numerical matrix

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to make a simple barplot with the data shown below

```
xx <- structure(list(13L, 65L, 569L, 452L, 7L, 11L, 58L, 134L, 18L, 
                     17L, 4L, 18L, 93L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 50L, 135L, 7L, 88L, 226L, 
                     179L, 0L, 0L, 44L, 121L, 17L, 191L, 1L), .Dim = 5:6, .Dimnames = list(
                       c("minus_2_H", "minus_H", "no_adduct", "plus_H", "plus_2H"
                       ), c("a", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z")))
```

however it only works for the

```
barplot (xx)
```

and fails with

```
barplot (xx, beside = TRUE)
```

> Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Could anyone clarify why its complaining even though the matrix is numeric in both cases?

Comment: You have a weird structure. Try `barplot(apply(xx, 2, unlist), beside = TRUE)`

Comment: yes it works thanks. I got this table by using do.call (cbind, myList)